# Barpots of item categories in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and not sure how to draw a bar plot of each category (6, 7) showing proportion (percentage) of "Wet" to other states in the following data frame:

```
Mine    Category    State
X23 6   Wet
M34 7   Wet
K28 7   Dry
U56 7   Swampy
S90 6   Wet
E35 7   Dry
X67 6   Wet
```

My effort so far:

```
sub =df.groupby(['Category','State==Wet'].sum()
sub.plot(kind='bar')
```

Can someone help please? Thanks

EDIT: This is the dataframe output to be plotted

```
Category    Percent “wet”   Percent “non wet”
6   3/3 (100%)  0/3 (0%)
7   1/4 ¾ ( 75 %)
```

So 6 and 7 on x-axis, then wet and non-wet stacked in each of bar(6) and bar(7).

Comment: Can you add desired output - dataframe?

Comment: Added Thanks @jezrael

Comment: Sounds like you want to pivot on the Category column and aggregate by percent. Let me see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function `f1` with `DataFrame constructor` and [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
def f1(x):
    return (sum(x == 'Wet') / float(len(x)))*100, (sum(x != 'Wet') / float(len(x)))*100

grouped = df.groupby(['Category'])['State'].apply(f1)

new_cols = ['wet','non-wet']
print pd.DataFrame(zip(*grouped), columns=grouped.index,index=new_cols).T
            wet  non-wet
Category                
6         100.0      0.0
7          25.0     75.0

sub.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and  help @jezrael. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use value_counts() and then plot the result. In my Dataframe I want to do this for the TestGroup column but you can do with the Category column.

```
df.TestGroup.value_counts(normalize= True).plot(kind = "bar")
```

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @bamdan, Thanks for your help. I have just edited my post. I think it wasn't clear enough that I wanted the  unique categories to be on x-axis. So there will be two columns showing the proportion of "Wet" to other states.